# Formula error "The formula you typed contains an error"

Tags: vba, excel

**I use excel 2010.**

I have the below formula that returns me an error

> The formula you typed contains an error

. Is there any way to resolve this? Thanks.

```
=loopThroughFilesCount2("C:\Users\yalinbah\Desktop\20180131_120549\New folder\ayakkabı\","A2")
```

**Here is my VBA formula**

```
Function loopThroughFilesCount2(dirFolder As String, strToFind As String) As Double

    Dim filePath As Variant
    filePath = Dir(dirFolder)
    While (filePath <> "")
        If InStr(filePath, strToFind) > 0 Then
            filesCount = filesCount + 1
        End If
        filePath = Dir
    Wend

    loopThroughFilesCount2 = filesCount

End Function
```

Problem is solved. Correct formula is below.

```
=loopThroughFilesCount2("C:\Users\yalinbah\Desktop\20180131_120549\New folder\ayakkabı\";A2)
```

Comment: Perhaps you need a semicolon rather than comma: `=loopThroughFilesCount2("C:\Users\yalinbah\Desktop\20180131_120549\New folder\ayakkabı\";"A2")`

Comment: That isn't a VBA error -- it is an error that Excel itself throws before the VBA is even called. @Rory is probably correct as to the source of the error (since it is syntactical rather than semantic).

Comment: Also I am guessing that you don't want the quotes around "A2"? You certainly want to find files with the value of *cell* A2 => No quotes.

Comment: @LocEngineer, the function defines `strToFind` as a string, so while it may or may not be looking for what he actually intends, I don't think that should throw the error. `FilesCount` also doesn't appear to be dimensioned anywhere; do you have `Option Explicit` turned on?

Comment: @TotsieMae My comment wasn't about the error, that is probably what Rory said: semicolon instead of comma due to localized Excel. Mine was just an additional remark.

Comment: Thank for your replies, I put ";" instead of "," and write directly A2 instead of "A2". My problem is solved thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. Correct formula is below.

```
=loopThroughFilesCount2("C:\Users\yalinbah\Desktop\20180131_120549\New folder\ayakkabı\";A2)
```